# Filtering the data in an array and return the adjusted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this :

```
const arr = [
              { name: 'A', accounts: [a, b]},
              { name: 'B', accounts: [c, d]},
              { name: 'C', accounts: [e, f]},
              { name: 'A', accounts: [g, h]},
              { name: 'B', accounts: [i, j]}
];
```

and I would like to modify this array like this :

```
const arr = [
              { name: 'A', accounts: [a, b, g, h]},
              { name: 'B', accounts: [c, d, i, j]},
              { name: 'C', accounts: [e, f]}
]
```

which means combining the account items with the object has same name.

This is how I tried :

```
returnGroupedArr = (arr) => {
              const result = arr.reduce((f, s) => {
                           f[s.name] = s[f.name];
                           f[s.name].push(s);
                           return f;
              }
}
```

Could you help me to figure out what i have missed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unconditionally reassigning a `name`'s accumulator property on every iteration.

To fix that, and to avoid mutating the input, create a new array for the name if it doesn't exist yet, and then push to it. Then transform it back into an array of objects by mapping its `Object.entries`:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'A', accounts: ['a', 'b']},
  { name: 'B', accounts: ['c', 'd']},
  { name: 'C', accounts: ['e', 'f']},
  { name: 'A', accounts: ['g', 'h']},
  { name: 'B', accounts: ['i', 'j']}
];

const groupedObj = arr.reduce((a, { name, accounts }) => {
  if (!a[name]) {
    a[name] = [];
  }
  a[name].push(...accounts);
  return a;
}, {});
const grouped = Object.entries(groupedObj)
  .map(([name, accounts]) => ({ name, accounts }));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const data = [
                  { name: 'A', accounts: ["a", "b"]},
                  { name: 'B', accounts: ["c", "d"]},
                  { name: 'C', accounts: ["e", "f"]},
                  { name: 'A', accounts: ["g", "h"]},
                  { name: 'B', accounts: ["i", "j"]}
    ];
    
    
    const newData = data.reduce((accum, curr, i) => {
        const atIndex = accum.findIndex((entry) => entry.name === curr.name);
        if(i !== atIndex && atIndex !== -1) {
            const mergedAccounts = accum[atIndex].accounts.concat(curr.accounts);
            return Object.assign([], accum, {[atIndex]: {...accum[atIndex], accounts: mergedAccounts}})
        }
        return accum.concat(curr);
    }, []);
    
    console.log(newData);
```

It's really just a Merge/De-Dupe in 1 loop